# PHP foreach loop show each list item while only showing list name once

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, foreach

Please compare the `CURRENT` and `DESIRED` results below to see what I'm trying to do.

```
$arr=array(
array('list_name'=>'Food', 'list_item'=>'bread'),
array('list_name'=>'Food', 'list_item'=>'meat'),
array('list_name'=>'Drinks', 'list_item'=>'water'),
array('list_name'=>'Drinks', 'list_item'=>'milk')
);

foreach($arr as $row){   
  echo $row['list_name'].'<br>'; 
  echo $row['list_item'].'<br>';
  echo '<br>___<br>';
}
```

CURRENT RESULT

```
Food
bread

___
Food
meat

___
Drinks
water

___
Drinks
milk

___
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
Food
1.bread
2.meat
___

Drinks
1.water
2.milk
___
```

**UPDATE**

More complex, yet more generalizable example:

```
$arr=array(
array('list_name'=>'Food', 'list_item1'=>'bread', 'list_item2' => 2001),
array('list_name'=>'Food', 'list_item1'=>'meat', 'list_item2' => 2002),
array('list_name'=>'Drinks', 'list_item1'=>'water', 'list_item2' => 2003),
array('list_name'=>'Drinks', 'list_item1'=>'milk', 'list_item2' => 2004)
);
```

DESIRED RESULT

```
Food
1.bread, 2001
2.meat, 2002
___

Drinks
1.water, 2003
2.milk, 2004
___
```

Comment: Why the downvotes? I think I've written a high-quality question.

Comment: I think you should describe your problem better...

Comment: Seems clear enough to me

Comment: I think its pretty self explanatory from the title and from comparing the current vs. desired result.

Comment: @IMSoP what are you saying is "clear"? How I've written the question or what the correct answer should be.

Comment: I believe he's saying that your problem is clear (contrary to jadkik94's opinion).

Comment: @MichaelRushton thanks, its kinda baffling sometimes on what gets upvoted vs. downvoted for a site that prides itself on being so objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could iterate over the array and add the item data to a new array (one for each `list_name`).

For example:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($arr as $row)
{
  $new_array[$row['list_name']][] = $row['list_item'];
}

foreach ($new_array as $name => $items)
{

  echo $name . '<br>'; 

  foreach ($items as $index => $item)
  {
    echo ($index + 1) . '. ' . $item . '<br>';
  }

  echo '___<br>';

}
```

With your update:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach ($arr as $row)
{

  $name = $row['list_name'];

  unset($row['list_name']);

  $new_array[$name][] = $row;

}

foreach ($new_array as $name => $items)
{

  echo $name . '<br>'; 

  foreach ($items as $index => $item)
  {
    echo ($index + 1) . '. ' . implode(', ', $item) . '<br>';
  }

  echo '___<br>';

}
```

Comment: Neat approach; I've appropriated some of your code as an alternative in my answer, as I've had reason to use both in the past :)

Comment: @MichaelRushton To make it more generalizable, i'm wondering how to extend your answer if the lists contained more items. I'm gonna add that to my question right now.

Comment: It'll work with any number of `list_items` and any number of `list_names`. Or do you mean if there's a further breakdown? E.g. Food => bread => Hovis?

Comment: @MichaelRushton No, no further breakdown. Can you see my updated answer/desired result? Sorry I'm just working this out now myself.

Comment: @MichaelRushton I'm certainly no coding guru. Would you consider this efficient or just a workable solution? Do you see a better way if I could re-do how I set up the data? Or should I not be caring about this stuff?

Answer (score 1):

One common recipe for this is to store the current heading/section into a variable as you loop over the list. Then each time you encounter a new heading, you echo that heading, and re-start your numbering (or close your HTML `<ol>` tag, etc).

```
$current_section = NULL;
foreach ( $arr as $row )
{
    if ( $current_section != $row['list_name'] )
    {
        // Begin new section
        echo $row['list_name'];
        // Remember current section
        $current_section != $row['list_name'];
    }

    // Output current item
    echo $row['list_item'];
}
```

Note that this approach will **only** work if your list is sorted such that all "food" items come together, then all "drinks", etc.

Otherwise, you can use the alternative approach of re-structuring your array so that there is a sub-array for each section, and then using a pair of nested loops:

```
$new_array = array();
foreach ($arr as $row)
{
    $new_array[$row['list_name']][] = $row['list_item'];
}

foreach ( $new_array as $section_name => $items )
{
    echo $section_name;
    foreach ( $items as $row )
    {
        echo $row;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$arr=array(
array('list_name'=>'Food', 'list_item'=>'bread'),
array('list_name'=>'Food', 'list_item'=>'meat'),
array('list_name'=>'Drinks', 'list_item'=>'water'),
array('list_name'=>'Drinks', 'list_item'=>'milk')
);

$names = array();

foreach ( $arr as $item){
    $name = $item['list_name'];
    if(!in_array($name, $names)){
        $names[] = $name;
        echo $name ."<BR>";
    }
    echo $item['list_item']."<BR>";
}
```

Comment: Could you add some commentary as to what this code is doing? If I read it right, this is the same as my first suggestion, but if the list is not sorted correctly, it will echo items under the wrong header, whereas mine would produce a duplicate header.

Comment: Have you tested either of yours? they don't work given the initial array

Comment: I was actually tempted to write mine in pseudo-code, as I was explaining the general pattern. If there are problems with them, please add as comments on my answer.