# PHP square bracket array adding another variable

Tags: php, arrays

I am not a programmer but have been using the suggestions on this topic - [PHP foreach loop show each list item while only showing list name once](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15178829/php-foreach-loop-show-each-list-item-while-only-showing-list-name-once)
It is to be incorporated into a report template to list purchases which are from several vendors, I have partly achieved some success using the below where 'meta' is the vendor's name:

```
<?php $new_array = array();
foreach ($order_items as $product) { 
$new_array[$product['meta']][] = $product['name'];
}
foreach ( $new_array as $section_name => $items )
{
echo $section_name;
foreach ( $items as $product )
{
echo $product. "<br>";
}
?>
```

My question is how can I introduce a third variable $product['quantity'] that will echo with the final $product?

I have tried all variants I have found but all failed so I assume I am making a basic error.

In an ideal world I would then like this to appear in a row in a table in the format  'meta'  'quantity', 'name'

This is for a not for profit venture. Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can do something like

```
  <?php $new_array = array();

    foreach ($order_items as $product) { 
    $new_array[$product['meta']][] = ['name' => $product['name'], 'quantity' => $product['quantity']];
    }
    foreach ( $new_array as $section_name => $items )
    {
    echo $section_name;
    foreach ( $items as $product )
    {
    echo $product['name']. "<br>";
    echo $product['quantity']. "<br>";
    }

?>
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you, more importantly though I can see where I was going wrong. Now to have a go at layout!

Comment: glad that you sorted out the issue, marking the answer as correct will be appreciated.

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that bit, have now done so, steep learning curve in all respects.